# GLM Define a vec3 after declaration

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to write a program using OpenGL. I am using the GLM header-only library for its vector and matrix functions, and I have run into something really weird.

I have a `glm::vec3` that I want to use as the position for an object, so I declare it in my header file (`glm::vec3 position;`) and then I want to actually set it in the object constructor (`position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)`). When I try to compile this, I get a **LNK2019** error.

#### To make diagnosing this easier, I have tested the following two pieces of code:

```
glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

and

```
glm::vec3 position;
position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

The first one compiles and runs absolutely fine.

#### The second one gets the LNK2019 error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct
glm::tvec3<float,0> & __thiscall glm::tvec3<float,0>::operator=(struct 
glm::tvec3<float,0> const &)" (??4?$tvec3@M$0A@@glm@@QAEAAU01@ABU01@@Z) 
referenced in function _main
```

I am probably missing something really obvious, but I cannot figure it out. I am using VS2010, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you messed with stuff like `GLM_PRECISION_LOWP_FLOAT` anywhere? `glm::vec3` in this case is `glm::tvec3<float,0>`, which is effectively an alias to `typedef detail::tvec3<float, highp> highp_vec3;` You can step through this stuff [here](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00134_source.html). _Can you show the sequence of includes you used to use the GLM template library in your code?_

Comment: My includes look like this so far:
'#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>' I haven't done anything with any #defines. I'm looking through the code you linked me to trying to understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with this myself. It appears that the issue is with the new version of GLM; 0.9.7.0. I downloaded each of the previous versions back to 0.9.5.4 and did not experience this issue.

Since the new version was uploaded less than a month ago I think I can assume there is some kind of bug with it.